# How to delete a file from GitHub history without using commandline

Tags: github

I need to remove a file from history. I don't have commandline access to GitHub. Kindly help if this can done through UI itself.

Comment: You should have command line access.
https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO achieve this, you have to have command line access.
[Delete file from history](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/)

But Using UI , you could delete the file from the repo (branch)
Ex:
[image]

Click the delete button on top right corner and commit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete the file from history, but you can delete it from the repository by following this [help article](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-files/)

Alternatively, you could do a cherry-picking using one of the Git GUIs software, then cherry-pick all the commits, except for the one that you wanted to removed, into a  new branch. Then, delete the old branch.

Comment: @BRjava I have committed the file again removing the sensitive data. The issue is the sensitive data is still there in history. I want to remove that

Comment: @vinod-d I added another solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need command line access to GitHub, only to your own local clone, where you can:

- either [do a `git filter-branch` (example here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872700/6309)
- or [use BFG](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)

Then you `git push --force`.

But the alternative, if you *really* don't want to use any command line, even locally... would be to [contact GitHub support](https://github.com/contact), asking them to remove the file from your remote repo history.
That is a last resort option though, since you are supposed to be able to do that on your own.